# xml serialization - How to add namespace in the sub node?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to serialize a xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MainNode xmlns="http://test">
  <SubNode xmlns:xsi="http://test2" xmlns="test3">
    <setting name = "1" value = "2"/>
  </SubNode>
</MainNode>
```

I created a class this like:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "test")]    
public class MainNode
{
    [XmlElement("SubNode")]
    public SubNode SubNode { get; set; }     
}

public class SubNode
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization fails because I have xmlns:xsi and xlms in my Sub Node. How should i include the namespace in my sub node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is quite a bit wrong with your approach. Hopefully this fully solves your issue, but nonetheless this will help at least get your structure correct.

You have a `SubNode` class with `Name` and `Value`. If you look at your XML, your `<SubNode>` does not contain these attributes/elements. It is your `<setting>` node that does. To fix this you need to create a `SubNode` and `setting` class.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://test")]
public class MainNode
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace="test3")]
    public SubNode SubNode { get; set; }
}

public class SubNode
{
    [XmlElement("setting")]
    public SettingsNode Settings { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsNode
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the `Namespace` set on the `XmlElementAttribute` on property `SubNode`. This should force all children (unless specifically overriden) that it is of that namespace.

I don't necessarily think you need to worry about the `xsi` attribute, but if you do, I believe you will need to look at the [XmlNamespaceDeclarationsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnamespacedeclarationsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This should at least get you the correct structure.

**EDIT:** Just tested and made a small correction. This appears to deserialize your example XML just fine. Here is my small test:

```
void Main()
{
    string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<MainNode xmlns=""http://test"">
  <SubNode xmlns:xsi=""http://test2"" xmlns=""test3"">
    <setting name = ""1"" value = ""2""/>
  </SubNode>
</MainNode>";

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainNode));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var result = (MainNode)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(result.SubNode.Settings.Value);
    }
}
```